# How to send an email using swiftmailer on a windows machine?

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

The swiftmailer documentation explains that for sending an email we have to create a Transport, mailer, message and then send it. Now i want to send an email from localhost and how to configure the transport for the windows machine.
The dummy code by their documentation is:

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.example.org', 25)->setUsername('your username')->setPassword('your password');
```

Now what should be the values of arguments so that being on windows i could send the mail from localhost. I 'm using Xampp.Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "sending from localhost" you only mean the script runs on localhost, but you are able to send the email from an external server, then you need an SMTP server you can use (for example the one you use for all your email anyway, whichever server that is) and use your credentials as long credentials in the transport. Nobody can tell you what that is, as we neither now your mail service, nor, obviously, your username and password there.

However if you do not have an external SMTP server to use, or do not want to use one, you need to run an SMTP server on your local machine. Covering how to set up an SMTP server on a windows machine is way outside the scope of SO. However I would not advise to do this outside of testing scenarios anyway, as mail originating from dynamic IP addresses (which you likely ahve) with no valid reverse DNS or reverse DNS that does not match the hostname (which you likely also have) is not accepted by any sane mails server anyway and considered spam.

Comment: Okk thanks a lot. I was learning swiftmailer. Just wanted to test it out but i think from your  answer that it is not possible to send one by simply a localhost and machine in hand.

Comment: If you're not running a mailserver on localhost, then yes, exactly that. However I assume you have an email address somewhere - you can easily use their SMTP server for testing. Just make sure the sender of your test emails is always your email address registered with that service, or else they will likely reject it.

Comment: can u explain how could i use that service as i am fairly new to PHP. I just want to see a test mail and swiftmailer in action.

Comment: Assuming your email address is "jot.waraich@gmail.com" you'd use

`$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl')->setUsername('jot.waraich@gmail.com')->setPassword('your gmail password');`


If you're not using gmail, find the right settings for your email service and adjust accordingly.

Note that Gmail requires encryption, therefore the additional 'ssl' argument.

Comment: You are great.Thanks